# How to `ediff-buffer` with ansi-colors (script output)? `ediff-file` works!

Tags: ediff

## Context: files with [ANSI and other terminal color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

I often record terminal transcripts using the traditional `script` program or `expect`.  Colored `ls` output, colored `grep` matches, [`mc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) and other interactive programs, everything works great and record is faithful!

## What works: replaying, opening in emacs

- One can replay such files in a terminal, either fast e.g. `cat` or on own rhythm using `less -r` (or `less -R` to see backspaces `^H` instead of obey them).
- One can open them in `emacs` and even have emacs automatically apply relevant mode, for example my `.emacs.d` applies this to any file matching `script_*.txt`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
        (when (string-match "script_.*\.txt$" (buffer-name))
              (progn
        (format-decode-buffer 'backspace-overstrike)
        (format-decode-buffer 'ansi-colors)
        (hide-dos-eol)
        (face-remap-add-relative 'default '((:foreground "white" :background "black")))
        ))))
```

## What fails: emacs accepts `ediff-files`, refuses `ediff-buffers`. Why? How to solve?

### Detail of what works: comparing with `ediff-files` works

This opens files straight into `ediff`, perfectly:

```bash
emacs --eval '(ediff-files "script_file1.txt" "script_file2.txt" )'
```

Differences are shown, colors from ANSI codes are blended with colors from `ediff` which was not expected as obvious.

Calling `ediff-files` interactively also works.

The fact is, I just figured out `ediff-files` works, while searching to write this question. I never `ediff-files` because it's much more convenient to open files with any of the convenient ways (`dired`, etc) then `ediff-buffer` after opening. `ediff-buffer` offers straightforward completion among the opened buffers, which is more selective/relevant.

### Detail of what fails: opening files interactively then invoking `ediff-buffers` fails

`ediff` doesn't start, minibuffer shows:

> "Sorry, `ansi-colors' format is read-only"

Notice that the very same buffers that have just been compared using `ediff-files`, when closing `ediff` then calling `ediff-buffers` yield same failure.

### Detail of what fails: saving file

Trying to save a file decoded with `tty-format`/`ansi-colors` fails, too.

## How to solve?

A good netizen searches before they ask.  Error message appears in package [tty-format](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TtyFormat).  Browsable copies of source code appear in various places, e.g. on https://github.com/grantdhunter/dotfiles/blob/8c11b417a373d4a8eb7a4b3772ebf956e825edfc/emacs.d/tty-format.el#L226

It looks like there is an avoidable obstacle.

It looks like buffers opened with ansi-color encoding have "lost something", they have been reencoded internally by emacs and cannot be saved again.  I can understand that ANSI codes that move cursor around to produce a composite buffer make not obvious what to do when saving again.

### Possible workaround: recovering convenience of `ediff-buffer`

I have an idea of a possible workaround but am not savvy enough in emacs-lisp.

Q1: Can someone make a function which would offer completion by buffer names (like `ediff-buffers`) but would actually figure out underlying files and calls `ediff-files` on them?

Any better idea is welcome.

### Possible workaround for impossibility to save: instruct emacs to save them into another format, possibly warning about lost information

This makes sense when saving snippets of text, e.g. as plain text, as color HTML, whatever. (Notice: `htmlize-buffer` does not fit, practically does no better than plain text.)

Q2: Is there a way to tell emacs "when saving this file, instead of refusing at all, offer me to save to a different location and format"?

I expect this would have a side-effect of allowing `ediff-buffers` to work immediately and lose color information, but maybe not.

### Something else?

Perhaps there is another way to handle files with ANSI color codes that doesn't have these problems at all?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing [tty-format](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TtyFormat) with [xterm-color](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color) appears to provide some of the expected benefits stated in the question text, while adding a risk of destroying information by overwrite with plain text.

### Cf. above "recovering convenience of ediff-buffer"

`ediff-buffer` works again.

### Cf. above "instruct emacs to save them into another format"

As soon as a buffer is opened, it is marked as "modified".

Saving it saves a plain-text version of the text, keeping normal characters, plus the obvious linefeed, plus BS (a.k.a. 0x08, `^H`) and CR (0x0D, `^M`).

### How to get this behavior

Here's how I adjust in `.emacs` my startup script to associate this to all files matching `script_*.txt`.

```lisp
(require 'xterm-color)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (string-match "script_.*\.txt$" (buffer-name))
              (progn
                (xterm-color-colorize-buffer)
                (hide-dos-eol)
                (face-remap-add-relative 'default '((:foreground "white" :background "black")))
                ))))
```

### What is not fully satisfying

One has to remember not to save file over the same name because it immediately destroys all existing color information.

Comment: This solution is not satisfying. Because emacs always considers files opened through `xterm-color` to be locally modified and insists on asking whether to save them all the time, I finally reverted back to the original situation.